# Access issue from Jasperserver while printing Image file from share drive

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am printing some Image file from share drive which I have the access from my local machine in Jaspersoft.

There is no issue while I am running .jrxml file from my local machine.

But while deployed .jrxml file in remote Jasperserver, it is asking for permission error is showing.

In this case which user need access to share drive ?

But, if server user is a local user on Server, then how can we give access to server user for n/w directories?

Answer (score 1):

Upload the image to JasperServer as an Image resource. You can do this by right-clicking on a folder and selecting Add Resource->File->Image.

Then access the image resource in your report using an expression. Something like this:

```
"repo:/public/Images/my_image"
```